# How to properly pivot or reshape a timeseries dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe, multi-index

I need to reshape a dataframe that looks like df1 and turn it into df2. There are 2 considerations for this procedure:

- I need to be able to set the number of rows to be sliced as a parameter (length).
- I need to split date and time from the index, and use date in the reshape as the column names and keep time as the index.

Current df1

```
2007-08-07 18:00:00    1
2007-08-08 00:00:00    2
2007-08-08 06:00:00    3
2007-08-08 12:00:00    4
2007-08-08 18:00:00    5
2007-11-02 18:00:00    6
2007-11-03 00:00:00    7
2007-11-03 06:00:00    8
2007-11-03 12:00:00    9
2007-11-03 18:00:00   10
```

Desired Output df2 - With the parameter 'length=5'

```
          2007-08-07  2007-11-02
18:00:00      1           6
00:00:00      2           7
06:00:00      3           8
12:00:00      4           9
18:00:00      5          10
```

What have I done:

My approach was to create a multi-index (Date - Time) and then do a pivot table or some sort of reshape to achieve the desired df output.

```
import pandas as pd 
'''
First separate time and date
'''
df['TimeStamp'] = df.index
df['date'] = df.index.date
df['time'] = df.index.time
'''
Then create a way to separate the slices and make those specific dates available for then create   
a multi-index.
'''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['Num'] = np.arange(len(df))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Num'] % 5 == 0:
        df.loc[index, 'EventDate'] = df.loc[index, 'Date']

df.set_index(['EventDate', 'Hour'], inplace=True)
del df['Date']
del df['Num']
del df['TimeStamp']
```

Problem: There's a NaN appears next to each date of the first level of the multi-index. And even if that worked well, I can't find how to do what I need with a multiindex df.

I'm stuck. I appreciate any input.

Comment: Can you include code for creation of df? (`df.to_dict()` for example)

Comment: @Korem I made the example by hand :(.....But I think you can use this dfx = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 0, 5, 1]}, index=pd.date_range('2011-1-2', '2011-01-03 20:00', freq='240T'))......use the parameter length=6 and you would be doing almost exactly the same.

Comment: Is it correct that the dates in your desired output do not correspond anymore with the dates in the input?

Comment: @joris Yes, because the important thing is that they correspond to the first row of every set of the length=5 in this example

Comment: Suppose the length were 4. What would the final index be?

Comment: @unutbu In this example it can not be 4. The parameter length, in this example has to be 5 . The parameter length is fit to the data I have so the hour part for the index matches for all columns when you reshape/pivot the df.

Comment: Is it intentional that the first and last hour, `18:00` repeats? Or in your actual data are the times unique? (The repeated hour makes `unstack` and `pivot` calls raise `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

Comment: @unutbu That is intentional, my actual data has that repeating timestamp feature. I would like to keep it like that, but I can also change it for the sake of solving this problem if a the alternative is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''\
                      val
2007-08-07 18:00:00    1
2007-08-08 00:00:00    2
2007-08-08 06:00:00    3
2007-08-08 12:00:00    4
2007-08-08 18:00:00    5
2007-11-02 18:00:00    6
2007-11-03 00:00:00    7
2007-11-03 06:00:00    8
2007-11-03 12:00:00    9
2007-11-03 18:00:00   10'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(data), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=True)

chunksize = 5
chunks = len(df)//chunksize

df['Date'] = np.repeat(df.index.date[::chunksize], chunksize)[:len(df)]
index = df.index.time[:chunksize]
df['Time'] = np.tile(np.arange(chunksize), chunks)
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Time'], append=False)

df = df['val'].unstack('Date')
df.index = index
print(df)
```

yields

```
Date      2007-08-07  2007-11-02
18:00:00           1           6
00:00:00           2           7
06:00:00           3           8
12:00:00           4           9
18:00:00           5          10
```

---

Note that the final DataFrame has an index with non-unique entries. (The
`18:00:00` is repeated.) Some DataFrame operations are problematic when the
index has repeated entries, so in general it is better to avoid this if
possible.

Comment: Great!. It works perfectly. Quick question: In case I needed to do df operations . I should just create a new index right?

Comment: Yes, you could use `reset_index`, or remove the line `df.index = index` above, or wait until the very end (until after all calculations are done) before tacking on the problematic index.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a canonical approach for pandas:

First, setup with imports and data:

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO


txt = '''2007-08-07 18:00:00 1
2007-08-08 00:00:00 2
2007-08-08 06:00:00 3
2007-08-08 12:00:00 4
2007-08-08 18:00:00 5
2007-11-02 18:00:00 6
2007-11-03 00:00:00 7
2007-11-03 06:00:00 8
2007-11-03 12:00:00 9
2007-11-03 18:00:00 10'''
```

Now read in the DataFrame, and pivot on the correct columns:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(txt), sep=' ', 
                  names=['d', 't', 'n'], )
print(df1.pivot(index='t', columns='d', values='n'))
```

prints a pivoted df:

```
d         2007-08-07  2007-08-08  2007-11-02  2007-11-03
t                                                       
00:00:00         NaN           2         NaN           7
06:00:00         NaN           3         NaN           8
12:00:00         NaN           4         NaN           9
18:00:00           1           5           6          10
```

You won't get a length of 5, though. The following,

```
          2007-08-07  2007-11-02
18:00:00      1           6
00:00:00      2           7
06:00:00      3           8
12:00:00      4           9
18:00:00      5          10
```

is incorrect, as you have 18:00:00 twice for the same date, and in your initial data, they apply to different dates.

Comment: Your approach did not work. Not even with your own code example. ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @hernanavella the output here is now correct, your desired output is impossible within the pandas framework.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm assuming your datetime column is actually a datetime type if not use `df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])` to convert.

Then set your index using a multindex and unstack...

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df['t'].apply(lambda x: [x.time(),x.date()]))
df['v'].unstack()
```

Comment: it is probably better to do datetime conversion doing `df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])` rather than call `apply`

Comment: @ZJS what is df['v'] ?

Comment: you didn't give column names df['t'] is the first column of your dataframe as a series

Comment: @ZJS but in the formula you wrote df['v'] also, is that a typo? or is the name of the second series?

Comment: df['v'] is the name of the second series/column